# Merge sorted arrays algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

I have to create algorithm for merging sorted arrays. Here is what I did:

```
import sys

lists = [[1,2,3], 
         [-100, 70], 
         [23, 50]]
pivot = [0] * len(lists) # [0, 0, 0]
finalSorted = []


for _ in range(sum(len(x) for x in lists)): # quantity of items in 2D array 
    smallest = sys.maxint
    index_of_smallest = -1      
    for indx, list in enumerate(lists):
        if pivot[indx] < len(list):
            current = list[pivot[indx]]
            if current <= smallest:
                smallest = current
                index_of_smallest = indx

    finalSorted.append(smallest)
    pivot[index_of_smallest] = pivot[index_of_smallest]+1

print(finalSorted) #[-100, 1, 2, 3, 23, 50, 70]
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this the best way of doing this?
2. Is algorithmic complexity `kn^2`? Where 'k' is average array length and `n` is quantity of arrays.
3. Is it good only for cases where `k` is much bigger then `n`? Where is the point of such `k` and `n` having which quicksort here become better solution?

Comment: I think there's a better solution with a heap.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/ `O(kn*logk)` using MinHeap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a popular programming interview question. The most elegant solution i saw so far was the following:

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue

def mergeKLists(lists):
    dummy = ListNode(None)
    curr = dummy
    q = PriorityQueue()
    for node in lists:
        if node: q.put((node.val,node))
    while q.qsize()>0:
        curr.next = q.get()[1]
        curr=curr.next
        if curr.next: q.put((curr.next.val, curr.next))
    return dummy.next
```

All Credit to> https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/33609/10-line-python-solution-with-priority-queue

Answer (score 0):

this is somewhat faster -- about 1.5x from my experimentation:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

final = []
second = lambda x: x[1]
while any(lists):
    idx, _ = min(enumerate(next(izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=sys.maxint))), key=second)
    final.append(lists[idx].pop(0))
```

EDIT: I guess if you're thinking about this in more of a theoretical sense (i.e. as an interview question) this isn't the best answer--a good example of using & abusing built-in python functions though :P

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite similar question on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/description/
which merge k sorted lists and the time complexity is O(Nlogk) where N is the total number of the k lists.

The algorithm's main method is to build a min heap of size k, and add elements to it. Since there was a detailed explanation on the leetcode website and I suggested you may take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Python's own standard lib provides a heap based solution `heapq.merge` which I would assume to be O(kn log n). I doubt you can do better than O(kn log n).

The [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/heapq.py) of `heapq.merge` is not too long, if you want to have a look.